# Can I have a single procedue instead of multple procedure for each userform control objects (Like common_combobox_change() method) in VBA?

Tags: vba, mousemove, ms-forms, control-array

I have a userform with multiple elements.

An example for changing the background of the control button upon mouse hovering. But for each button I need to define the predefined `Button_MouseMove(....)` function.

I would like to have a single function which takes control object as argument for any the control objects.

For example.

I am currently using this procedure

```vb
Private Sub btnrefresh_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    If Me.btnrefresh.Enabled = True Then Me.btnrefresh.BackColor = &H9CED4B
End Sub
```

But I need some procedure looks like this

```vb
Public sub Any_Button_MouseHovering(Byval Button as object)
    if (coordinates of mouse falls inside the button area) then    'I need to know procedure for this also
        If button.Enabled = True Then Button.BackColor = &H9CED4B
    else
        Button.BackColor = vbWhite
    end if
end sub
```

Comment: You need a class module, e.g. something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370449/perform-similar-mouse-events-for-all-the-labels-in-userform-using-vba-class-modu